# проблема с выводом строки

Tags: c++, строки, вывод

допустим мой ввод:

```
1
[lalala]1313боец
```

но моим выводом, вместо
    `lalala` оказывается пустая строка, почему так происходит?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

enum Role{
Boec,Klirik
};

struct answer{
string get;
int lvl;
string name;
Role r;

};

main()
{
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
     int N;
cin>>N;
answer* d=new answer [N];
int p=0;
 while(( p)!=N)
{cin >> d[p].get;
p++;
}


for (int v=0;v<N;v++){
        stringstream inp(d[v].get);
         inp >> d[v].lvl;
    int u=d[v].get.find("лекарь"); if (u==-1) d[v].r=Boec; else d[v].r=Klirik;
inp.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '[');
getline(inp, d[v].name, ']');


                        }
cout<<d[0].name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в последовательности чтения из потока. При любом чтении из потока вы меняете его внутренее состояние (изменяется текущая позиция, например в потоке нельзя читать "назад"). Т.о. вы сначала читаете `int`, прочитать его не удается и дальнейшее чтение невозможно (устанавливается флаг `failbit`). Проверить это можно написав небольшую функцию

```
string get_state(ios_base::iostate state) {
    string state_str = "";
    if(state & ios_base::eofbit) {
        state_str += "|eofbit|";
    }
    if(state & ios_base::failbit) {
        state_str += "|failbit|";
    }
    if(state & ios_base::badbit) {
        state_str += "|badbit|";
    }
    return state_str.empty() ? "|goodbit|" : state_str;
}
```

Она вернет состояние потока в виде строки. Теперь преобразуем код вашего цикла

```
inp >> d[v].lvl;

cout << "position = " << inp.tellg() << ", state = " << get_state(inp.rdstate()) << endl;

inp.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '[');
getline(inp, d[v].name, ']');

cout << "position = " << inp.tellg() << ", state = " << get_state(inp.rdstate()) << endl;

cout << d[v].lvl << endl;
cout << d[v].name << endl;
```

Вывод получим следующий

> ```
> position = -1, state = |failbit|
> position = -1, state = |failbit|
> 0
> ```

Как видите сразу после первого чтения ошибка. Исправить это можно изменив последовательность чтения

```
inp.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '[');
getline(inp, d[v].name, ']');

cout << "position = " << inp.tellg() << ", state = " << get_state(inp.rdstate()) << endl;

inp >> d[v].lvl;

cout << "position = " << inp.tellg() << ", state = " << get_state(inp.rdstate()) << endl;

cout << d[v].lvl << endl;
cout << d[v].name << endl;
```

И соответствующий вывод

> ```
> position = 8, state = |goodbit|
> position = 12, state = |goodbit|
> 1313
> lalala
> ```